# Where does Angular JS fit in the browser rendering process?

Tags: html, angularjs, browser

From my understanding the browser rendering process is essentially happening in the following steps:

1. HTML is parsed into DOM tree
2. DOM tree is converted to a render tree
3. Layout
4. Paint

Where does Angular JS come in the picture here? For example if I have an expression like

```
<div>{{test}}</div>
```

or

```
<div ng-include="..."></div>
```

Is it right to think that Angular does the interpolation or HTML injection, and then the browser takes the resulting HTML code, and goes through steps 1-4?

Comment: This should be very easy to find with an online search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular JS documentation says:

> When Angular starts your application, it parses and processes this
>   new markup from the template using the [compiler](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler). The loaded,
>   transformed and rendered DOM is basically the view

Here a template means:

> HTML code that contains Angular specific attributes.

For more information on how AngularJs works and what it can do, please read the documentation provided:

> https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts

There is an in-depth tutorial which provide more information on it.

I hope this could help you get started with it :)